# How to get items to dropdown list in a field using jsGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jsgrid

This is a jQuery code of my sample project to get details from application side to display in front in a grid which is build by jsGrid.

```
$("#part_table").jsGrid({
            height: "auto",
            width: "100%",
            autoload: true,
            editing: true,
            sorting: true,
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            inserting: true,
            loadIndication: false,
            filtering: true,
            headerRowClass: 'table-green-header',
            controller: {
                loadData: function (filter) {
                    function.....
                },
                updateItem: function (item) {

                    function.....

                }
            },
            fields: [
                { name: "Id", type: "number", visible: false },
                {
                    name: "CatalogueId", type: "select", **items**: catalouges, valueField: "Id", textField: "CatalougeName", selectedIndex : -1 , title: "Catalouge Name", align: "center"
                },

                { name: "DistributorPrice", type: "number", title: "Distributor Price", align: "center", filtering: false, sorting: false },
                { name: "IsActive", type: "checkbox", filtering: false, sorting: false },
                { type: "control" }


            ],
            rowClick: function (args) {
                return false;
            },
        });
```

Can anyone say how to get a list of items to field by calling to application side via AJAX call ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load items in advance and then use result in the grid field config, e.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/countries/"
}).done(function(countries) {

    countries.unshift({ id: "0", name: "" });

    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        ...,
        fields: [
            ...
            { name: "country_id", title: "Country", type: "select", width: 100, items: countries, valueField: "id", textField: "name" }
        ]
    });

});
```

You can find an example in the [jsgrid sample project](https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid-php/blob/master/public/js/sample.js)

Comment: Hi @tabalin ; if there were than additional `select field` which required an additional AJAX `GET`, how would the code be structured? If I nest them as `ajax1{ajax2{jsgrid{}}}` it works. Is there a cleaner way of separating out the code?

Comment: @tabalin is there any way to have multi select contries in this example? and would get the more the one selection here?

Comment: @AjitHogade, check out this example to see how to implement multiselect http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/qg4et3ey/16/

Answer (score 1):

You can do multiple simultaneous requests before the grid launches

```
$.when(

    $.get("/api/v1/clients", function(clients) {
        db.clients = clients;
    }),

    $.get("/api/v1/owners", function(owners) {
        db.owners = owners;
    })

).then(function() {

    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        ...,

        fields: [
            { name: "client", title: "Client", type: "select", items: db.clients, valueField: "name", textField: "name" },
            { name: "owner", title: "Owner", type: "select", items: db.owners, valueField: "short_name", textField: "short_name" },

        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you write the ajax call in loadData of the controller.. something like:

```
controller: {
                loadData: function(filter) {
                    return $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/api/data",
                        data: filter,
                        dataType: "json"
                    });
}                    
}
```

further reference https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid-webapi

Comment: in this way i can load data into grid. But  my grid has a drop-down list (1-to-many relationship) , then i want to go to edit mode, i need to populate that drop down, in jsgrid there is a field property to set data list to that drop-down, but i want to know is there any chance to load data via AJAX call to that feild item property .